# How did ships return to Earth space after enacting the Cole Protocol?

Tags: halo

The Cole Protocol says that ships have to purge nav database when encountering an enemy. OK, that makes sense.

But in the case they win the battle, **how do they find their way back to human controlled space?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Halo: Evolutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765315734) makes a reference to a "*Cole Protocol return trip*", basically after executing a series of random slipstream jumps, the ship is then  allowed to travel to a known location (in this case, back to Reach base) in order to collect Navigational data to allow onward travel.

> Find out what had happened on Algolis and make sure the weapons
>   prototypes were completely eradicated. **Then loop back on a complex and
>   slow Cole Protocol return trip.**

---

As to how this is possible, it's perhaps worth noting that the [Cole Protocol](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/United_Nations_Space_Command_Emergency_Priority_Order_098831A-1) relates to navigational data **relating to Earth and the inner colonial planets**. Presumably a small amount of Nav data can be held by the ship's crew that would allow them to travel to a neutral location or an armed Earth base.

> *All UNSC and civilian ships which come in contact with alien assets
>   must have NAV computer/AI erased—destroyed if necessary—**to prevent
>   capture of core world locations.***

Alternatively, they may simply be relying on the good old *point'n'shoot* approach, with ships heading toward known galactic structures until they get back to Earth-controlled space.

Comment: need to read the book.. how is it connected to halo universe? Meaning when should I read it? Or it doesn't matter? EDIT: to explain, I'm reading all the books and I'm just finishing the first one, so I wonder where should I put this one

Comment: @Paladin - Reading order questions are very much on-topic on the main board. Ask the question there :-)